# Excel in multiple formats

Tags: ai-design

I want to use AI to extract data from spreadsheets in different format.

Example

```
Shop Name Product 1.  Product 2.  Product 3.
Shop Name
Product 1.
Product 2.
Product 3.
```

We will teach the algorithm the name of the profits and shops but it needs to know how to extract and put in a format that can be used downstream.

Can anyone recommend a tool?

Comment: What do you mean by " extract data from spreadsheets in different format.". Even with the example, it is not clear. Please, clarify your question a little more.

Comment: more elaboration is needed,for effective feedback!

Answer (score 1):

The question would need clarification. I'm new here so I will try to give an answer.
The easiest way would be to prepare the data in comma separated values (CSV). It is possible to export your data in this format from excel.
For downstream applications it will depends what programming language is used but in general it is possible to import CSV files and the data they contain for training (example panda data frame in python).

Hope this helps!